# Integrating a function over a variable other than the first, looking for an alternative to lambda

Tags: python, lambda, quad

Is there any other way than using a lambda function to integrate a function in python 2.7 over, say, the 2nd of two variables? For instance, I would like to integrate this example function over x:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def sqrfn(a,x):
    return a*np.square(x)
```

This is easily achieved by:

```
quad(lambda x: sqrfn(2,x),0,10)
```

I'm wondering if there is another way to do this, for instance by using something similar to, which I think is much more intuitive:

```
quad(sqrfn,0,10,args(a=2))
```

Anyone got an alternative solution? (Yea, I could define the function as `sqrfn(x,a)` and use `quad(sqrfn,0,10,args(2,))` instead, but that's not the point).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for this:

```
In [10]: f = functools.partial(sqrfn, 2)
```

This makes `f(x)` equivalent to `sqrfn(2, x)`:

```
In [11]: map(f, range(5))
Out[11]: [0, 2, 8, 18, 32]
```

Your example would then become:

```
quad(functools.partial(sqrfn, 2), 0, 10)
```

Comment: What would happen with this method if I had an n variable function and I would want to fix all but the k'th variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools
quad(functools.partial(sqrfn, 2), 0, 10)
```